# How to handle a previous Flyway migration becoming invalid in newer DB versions?

Tags: mariadb, flyway

So, I have a Flyway migration which applied successfully, years ago, to an older version of MariaDB.

A newer release of MariaDB is now more strict, and causes an error on that same migration. There's a legit issue with that migration that I want to fix for both fresh runs from the baseline (e.g. building in my CI environment, or on a new devleoper's laptop), and for all of my existing databases (before I attempt to upgrade them to a newer MariaDB release, which may just fail).

What's the right solution?

- Alter the migration, and add a new one that does the same fix (another ALTER TABLE ...) that'll effectively be a noop for the newly created DBs, but will fix my existing stuff.
- Add a new migration versioned out-of-order, just prior to the broken one, which fixes the issue. Hopefully that means new DBs will apply that just before the broke migration, and existing installs will apply it before any of my newer migrations?

To be specific, the issue was that I was migrating a table which was originally using `ENGINE=MyISAM ROW_FORMAT=FIXED` to `ENGINE=InnoDB` -- MariaDB 10.1 accepts that, but newer MariaDB releases seem to fail unless I also add `ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT`.

---

#### Baseline

```sql
CREATE TABLE FOO ( ... )
   ENGINE=MyISAM ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
```

#### Later Migration

```sql
ALTER TABLE FOO
  ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

That latter statement fails on a newer MariaDB release (and possibly for MySQL too, not sure?).

This statement works, though:

```sql
ALTER TABLE FOO
  ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT;
```

The issue is that the previous statement internally tries to do something like this, which fails:

```sql
CREATE TABLE FOO ( ... )
   ENGINE=InnoDB ROW_FORMAT=FIXED;
```

Comment: This does not apply to mysql - it implies ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT if ROW_FORMAT option is left out. Therefore removed the mysql tag.

Comment: I'm not sure that quite matches the situation here, please review my revisions above and let me know if that still matches for you?

Comment: Still no problem on mysql. Mysql documentation explicitly says `When a ROW_FORMAT option is not specified explicitly, or when ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT is used, an operation that rebuilds a table silently changes the row format of the table to the format defined by the innodb_default_row_format variable.` The emphasis is on the silently, meaning no warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is probably to carefully modify the migration and issue a `flyway repair` to realign the checksums in the database with the new ones on disk.

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB does not have a ROW_FORMAT=FIXED. In older versions, the variable innodb_strict_mode is set to 0, in which case a warning is issued, and ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT is used when converting.

```
ALTER TABLE FOO ENGINE=InnoDB;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.07 sec)    
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql [localhost] {msandbox} (test) > SHOW WARNINGS;
+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                              |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1478 | InnoDB: assuming ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT. |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------+
```

In newer versions innodb_strict_mode is set to 1, so an error is returned.

```
ALTER TABLE FOO ENGINE=InnoDB;
ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `test`.`FOO` (errno: 140 "Wrong create options")
```

You can set the variable 0 for the duration of the session in order to replicate the old behaviour.

```
set innodb_strict_mode=0;
```

References:

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/xtradbinnodb-strict-mode/
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_strict_mode
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/myisam-storage-formats/#fixed-length
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-storage-formats/

Comment: Thanks, though my question is more specific to how to deal with this in the context of [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/). I understand that the behavior around "strict mode" changed, and I just want to fix these otherwise "immutable" past migrations to behave properly in that strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

Setup mariadb 10.1 to strict mode let me export and import the data on mariadb 10.3

wrong create table options error message is gone.

```
set innodb_strict_mode=0;
```

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-strict-mode/